# Need a backwards way to identify what certificate I am checking

Tags: c#, encryption

I am new to a project using C# ASP. One part in the code encrypts a hashcode in a URL link to be sent in an email via some shortcode processing on the email template. The encryption we are using is symmetric Rijndael with the CryptographyManager class. This was implemented long before my (or anyone else on the team's) tenure here, so we do not know how this was setup originally (i.e. what the certificate name was/is). So what ends up happening is our code runs fine on The test/UAT/production server, and our nightly process server, but whenever we debug this code on our own machines, we get this error:

> Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException: Activation
>   error occured while trying to get instance of type
>   CryptographyManager, key "" --->
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the
>   dependency failed, type =
>   "Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.Cryptography.CryptographyManager",
>   name = "(none)".

Granted, my thought is that I am missing the private key/certificate store on my machine to complete such a task. So I took a look at certmgr on the server and found 370 certificates, with no obvious names tying themselves to our project. Joy.

So I went back into the code to see if I could breakpoint my way to an understanding of where we are looking:

```
public static MyEmailViewModel GetEmailTemplateBody(string templateName, string MasterID)
{
        MyEmailViewModel email = new MyEmailViewModel();
        EmailShortCodeProvider emailShortCodeProvider = new EmailShortCodeProvider(new ParticipantRepository(),
            new MyEncryptionProvider(EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<CryptographyManager>()));
...
```

And I am failing on the last line above. My main suspicion is that whatever instance of CryptographyManager the EnterpriseLibraryContainer is trying to resolve is missing the cert name and key (if I am interpreting that error message correctly), yet the object is not null...just in need of setup.

Checking the web.config file:

```
  <securityCryptographyConfiguration defaultHashInstance="SHA1CryptoServiceProvider" defaultSymmetricCryptoInstance="RijndaelManagedServiceProvider">
    <hashProviders>
      <add name="SHA1CryptoServiceProvider" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithmProvider, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.Cryptography, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" algorithmType="System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" saltEnabled="true" />
    </hashProviders>
    <symmetricCryptoProviders>
      <add name="RijndaelManagedServiceProvider" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithmProvider, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.Cryptography, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" algorithmType="System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" protectedKeyFilename="C:\xxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxx.key" protectedKeyProtectionScope="LocalMachine" />
    </symmetricCryptoProviders>
  </securityCryptographyConfiguration>
```

I would think my trouble would be over if I could copy that key specified by the protectedKeyFilename tag, but no luck. Keys tend to be machine specific, and to export them from the server, most instructions require exporting using certmgr and I need a certificate name for that to happen.

I've spent days looking into this with lots of information absorbed, but no tangible progress. Does anyone have a clue on how I can get the certificate name in any fashion? Am I completely wrong and I need no certificate, just a really good key? I am frustrated and overwhelmed to the point where I am not sure if I am asking the right questions or providing the right info. Any help or pointers are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Summary: New to encryption, using old Microsoft CryptographyManager, I think I need to find cert name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was asking the wrong questions. There was no way to get that certificate name in a backwards manner (to my knowledge). I did find the certificate, but it was not in any of my real certificate stores.

I logged onto the server and brought up the IIS manager (6.0). Under the machine -> Web Sites -> Default Web Site (or whatever the site name is), right-click Properties -> Directory Settings -> Under the Secure Communications section, you can view the certificate, or modify/copy it via the "Server Certificate" button.

In my strange case, the certificate was custom-built (we have a department that manages these), and the certificate path was issued via an intermediary certificate.